# How do I round a number to two decimals in SQL commander in DBV?

Tags: decimal, dbvisualizer

I am dividing two numbers, where numerator is smaller than denominator. I was expecting some numbers between 0 and 1 but I always get 0 without any decimals. I would like to see at least one decimal. I tried the round function but it isn't working for me. What should I do?

Edit: the two numbers are integers in millions.

I tried round function but it didn't do the trick.

Comment: What are the data types of your numerator and denominator? If one of them is an integer you'll get integer division causing your 0 result.

Comment: Yes, integers in millions. both the numbers are.

Comment: In that case you need to cast them to a decimal data type, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your numbers are integers, so if you try to divide them it will be [integer division](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-division-operator/). To get around this you need to cast one (or both) of your numbers to a decimal data type:

```sql
SELECT CAST(your_numerator AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / your_denominator AS rounded_value
FROM your_table;
```

The `DECIMAL(10, 2)` function means you can store numbers with up to 10 digits in total, where 2 of those digits are reserved for the decimal part, e.g. `12345.67` (10 digits in total, 2 decimal places)`. Obviously you can change these numbers if you want more decimal places.

Comment: I tried this round(cast(num as decimal(9,2))/den,2)*100. It gives me decimals of 00 only.

Comment: round((cast(num as decimal(9,2))/den)*100,2) this works